# AppstartSaver works but app crashes upon "waking up"

Tags: macos, processing, screensaver

I have an app from processing that works in the preview for screen saver on mac. But upon waking up the computer the app crashes.

Any reasons why and any tips to help?

Thanks for your help.

edit : this is the message that I get randomly. This doesn't happen all the time.["The Crash"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdbTK.png)

edit #2 : [After clicking report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNz7t.png)

after clicking show details look at comments for paste bin link.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it crashes? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I added a screen cap of what happens

Comment: Can you get any more information, maybe if you click the report button?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/t03jkm3u pastebin link they won't let me post more than 2 links ....